# Adding a ListItem to the top of a ListBox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have the **ListBox** below and would like to know how I would be able to add a **ListItem** to the **ListBox** which is not coming form the **SQLDataSource**. I want to add a Zero at the top of the this **ListBox** and then add the data coming from the **SQLDataSource**.

```html
<asp:ListBox 
    ID="ListBox4" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="getAvaibleChapters" 
    DataTextField="chapterNo" 
    DataValueField="chapterNo" 
    Rows="1"  
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("no") %>' />



 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="getAvaibleChapters" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RXIConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT chapterNo FROM Chapters WHERE (subjectID = @subjectid) order by chapterNo asc">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="subjectid" QueryStringField="subjectid" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: can you show the getAvaibleChapters code?

Comment: I have added the code for you to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this .. it may help you .

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "---Select an item---" };
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
        cmbProName.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
        cmbProName.ValueMember = "PID";
        cmbProName.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the DataSource SQL statement like something below

```
select 0, 'select all'
UNION 
select chapterNo, no from  Chapter
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baad6/2

Answer (score 0):

This is the best method of doing this,,

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
 chapterNo int
)
insert @temp
values (0);
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT chapterNo FROM Chapters WHERE subjectID = @subjectid;
select * from @temp order by chapterNo asc
```